# Google Custom Search Engine search bar within navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I made a horizontal navigation bar using [w3schools' tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar_horizontal.asp) which ended up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rgvP.png) but when I add the search bar, [everything messes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj7q2.png). How do I fix this?

Heres my code:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a class="text" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="text" href="#">About Us</a></li>
    <li>
        <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=006548796792344891984:w08mnitgeri"></script>
        <div class="gcse-search"></div>
    </li>
    <li style="float: right"><a class="text" href="#">Log-in</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
  
li {
    float: left;
}
  
li a.text {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 92px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

li a.logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 16px;
}
  
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attached code it will surely work and if not comment your problem and i will try my best to help you.

In the code below I have made an id named `gs` which takes care of alignment and size of search bar.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}
  
li {
    float: left;
}
  
li a.text {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 92px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

li a.logo {
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 16px;
}
  
li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
#gs{
    width: 72vw;
    padding-top: 10vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li><a class="logo" href="index.html"><img src="Logo.png"></a></li>
    <li><a class="text" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="text" href="">About Us</a></li>
    <li>
        <script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=006548796792344891984:w08mnitgeri"></script>

        <div class="gcse-search" id="gs"></div>
    </li>
    <li style="float: right"><a class="text" href="#">Log-in</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I had to lower the width a bit more but it worked.

Comment: @timothy5597 You're Welcome. I hope I get more chances to help you and can you please do me a favour by accepting and upvoting the answer, it would mean a lot to me.

Comment: Sure! no problems

Comment: @timothy5597 Thanks for accepting the answer, you have made my day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the search bar in same alignment with other `li` elements, just add this to the style code:

```
li > div {
  margin-top: 92px;
}
```

This `li > div` is a kind of CSS selectors that you can read more about on this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). And you can after that customize the layout as you want.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. https://pasteboard.co/JicEQYX.png

Comment: Well, I just copied your code above and this was the result: https://b.top4top.io/p_1660numl22.png then when i add `li > div {margin-top: 92px;}` this was the result: https://a.top4top.io/p_1660s5sg21.png So are you sure this isn't any missed code?

Comment: huh, what browser are you using? I tried on Google Chrome and Microsoft edge and neither worked

Comment: Why don't try to add a max width? `li { max-width: 50%;}`